# Animating "fillColor" property in Animated Vector Drawable

Tags: android, animation, android-vectordrawable

In my app I'm using an arrow as a drawable, for which I'd like to animate the fillColor property. I came across AnimatedVectorDrawable examples which modify properties such as pathData, transateY/X, rotation etc., How do I animate the fillColor property, so that my arrow changes color periodically?

Comment: Are there specific problems you're having making this work? There's a basic example of a fillColor AnimatedVectorDrawable in the new SO Documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1627/vectordrawable-and-animatedvectordrawable/5267/basic-animatedvectordrawable#t=201607281801296008494

Answer (score 0):

The function animate() haven't got a method to change fillColor directly, but you can do a litle trick. In the next code I show you how use the function animate() to simulate the change of fillColor using the function animate twice:

```
drawableView.animate()
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setDuration(100)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        /*
        In this point you can change de color of drawable, 
        the color or property that you want to change (title, color, size...)
        */
        drawableView.animate()
            .alpha(1.0f)
            .setDuration(100)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
     }
});
```

Using code above, you can change some property of drawable inside the animation, I mean, the proccess will be the next: 
1 - Animation do that the drawable disappear (alpha 0)
2 - You change the property you want
3 - Animation do that the drawable appear again (alpha 1)

If you use this code inside Timer, you can do that the drawable change the color periodically.